# Comma separated values from SQL not working in Delimited(CSV) file

Tags: sql, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have a sproc written to output around 10 values with ',' separated. So my output will be like :
a,b,4,r,6,7,etc. 
I have an export setup on the front end to pull out this output into Delimited(CSV) format, excel, xlsx and HTML formats. The output is working fine as above when exported to Excel file, however the output doesn't work with ',' when exported to Delimited(CSV). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does it mean, "doesn't work"? Machine stop, segfault, no output, corrupt output, ...?

Comment: I get an output without ','(mentioned in the question - read carefully). My output is like: a b 4 r 6 7

Comment: Show your code that builds the delimited string!